# How to convert msg.data to a uint

Tags: solidity

I am sending ETH to a contract as follows:

`web3.eth.sendTransaction({from: sender, to: address, value:amount, gas:300000, data:"1234"});`

In my fallback function, I can see `msg.data` has the following value (as expected):

"0x1234"

The trouble is (and I've been at this for hours...) how do I convert this into a `uint` holding the value 1234?

Here's my attempt that sorta works (i.e. doesn't):

```
function bytes2uint(bytes _data) constant returns(uint){
    uint i=0;
    uint dec=0;

    for (i = 0; i < _data.length; i++) {
        byte e=_data[_data.length-i-1];
        uint f=uint(e);
        f=((f/16)*10)+(f%16);
        dec+=(f*(100**i));
    }
    return dec;
}
```

I am able to successfully convert "0x1234", "0x123456", "0x12", etc. (i.e. an even number of digits). However, when I try "0x123" or "0x12345" (for example), the trailing digit is somehow getting truncated?

Answer (score 6):

You just use

```
 web3.toHex(1234)
```

Converting to other types is also supported https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API

Comment: I'm trying to make it as "easy" as possible for my users to interact with my contract. `web3.toHex` or `web3.fromDecimal` is verbose and I was trying to find a way of omitting them.