# Solidity: Is there a way to get the timestamp of a transaction that executed?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, timestamp

Is there a way for a contract to be able to get the exact time someone called a function in it?

For example, if someone sends funds to the contract address, is there a timestamp recorded by the blockchain that would give the received time of this transaction?

And if so, how would I get this value in Solidity and would the timestamp of this transaction be modifiable by the user in any kind of way once it is sent?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A transaction doesn't have a timestamp. However, every block provides a timestamp (when it was collected), but if the time is critical for you, don't refer to this `timestamp` because a miner could modify it by about 900s. Instead, you could use `block.number`.

1- current block timestamp is returned by `now`:

e.g.

```
contract Test {
    function Time_call() returns (uint256){
        return now;
    }
}
```

`Time_call()` will return something like `1478431966` (which you could convert into a readable form in https://www.unixtimestamp.com/).

2- block number is returned using `block.number`:

```
 function Time_call() returns (uint256){
        return block.number; 
    }
```

to get the call time, you could use the `block.number` and the [block time](https://etherscan.io/chart/blocktime) (an average).

**Edit**: if you want when the transaction was sent, use JavaScript in your Dapp to get the current time `var seconds = new Date().getTime();` and send it in the data field within your transaction.

Comment: @Badr_Bellaj if I am not mistaking, this returns the timestamp of the block and not of the time the transaction was received/sent. Am I correct? Because what I need is to get the time the transaction was sent not the time it was executed at.

Comment: it is impossible to get when the transaction was sent, there is no timestamp in the transaction. besides, we don't know how time it was on the pool or when it was signed. However you could write a dapp using web3js which send such information withing the transaction.

Comment: check the edit for more details

Comment: @Badr_Bellaj How do you then interact with data in the data field in solidity?

Comment: by using msg.data

Comment: read also http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2205/how-to-convert-msg-data-to-a-uint

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is important for us to remember that if we want to send timestamp from Javascript to solidity, we will need to convert it into seconds like so `var seconds = new Date().getTime() / 1000;`. this will not work `var seconds = new Date().getTime()`. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You can use `block.timestamp` to get the current block timestamp

Reference:

[Solidity Docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=block#block-and-transaction-properties)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the keyword `now` to get the current timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

below code will store time at which `updateTime()` is called, and get that call time by `getTime`.

```
contract calculateTime{
    uint calcTime=0;
    function updateTime() public{
        calcTime=block.timestamp;
    }
    function getTime() public view returns(uint){
        return calcTime;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

contract Time{

   uint public blockTime;

    function getCurrentTime() public {
        blockTime = block.timestamp;
    }

}
```