# How to use a date time from an API to prevent contract interactions if the date is a string?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-invocation, contract-debugging

I want an to use an oracle to prevent contract interaction after certain time cutoffs

This is the APIs format:

"event":"event2","timezone":"UTC+1","datetime":"2018-06-07 01:00:00"

I think doing all of the calculation in the contract would be very expensive to convert to unix time/bytes and is seems complicated with timezones.

I cannot change the API (not my API), I would prefer to not build my own API.

Does anyone have any thoughts on how to handle this?

Comment: I don't see any right solution to this. I would make a proxy that format the datetime (timestamp) and connect Oraclize to the proxy.

Answer (score 0):

You may think about using a timestamp to control the date of each Transaction.
here is a similar topic about that:
[Solidity: Is there a way to get the timestamp of a transaction that executed?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9858/solidity-is-there-a-way-to-get-the-timestamp-of-a-transaction-that-executed)

Answer (score 0):

I think the oracle is not needed. You could just save as a constant the timestamps after which the function will not be executed and `require(now < contantTimeStamp)`

Hope this helps