# Reference of a transaction date

Tags: datetime

I am building a lotery with one game per day on Ethereum but I need to know what is time zone is the transaction date in Solidity.

Is it gmt+0?

Comment: Can you indicate the function you use to get the date in solidity ? Or have a look at https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9858/solidity-is-there-a-way-to-get-the-timestamp-of-a-transaction-that-executed

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is GMT+0 or UTC.

According to Ethereum Yellow Paper the **timestamp** in a block is a unix timestamp.

> **timestamp**: A scalar value equal to the reasonable
>   output of Unix’s time() at this block’s inception;
>   formally H<sub>s</sub>.

Now from wikipedia

> **Unix time** (also known as **POSIX time** or **UNIX Epoch time**) is a system for describing a point in time, defined as an approximation of the number of seconds that have elapsed since 00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), Thursday, 1 January 1970.

Answer (score 0):

## block.timestamp

From Solidity docs

> block.timestamp (uint): current block timestamp as seconds since unix epoch

It's a UNIX timestamp. Also `now` is an alias for `block.timestamp`.

---

A few things to keep in mind:

> I need to know what is time zone is the transaction date in Solidity

You only get the block timestamp, not the transaction timestamp.

> a lotery with one game per day

Miners (esp. mining pools) can potentially adjust the timestamp as they mine, so you should design your lottery in a way that it's not entirely timestamp dependent.