# How to know the execution time of transaction when miner execute it

Tags: web3js, contract-invocation, javascript, nodejs, raw-transaction

When i send three consecutive transactions to my contract (deployed on ethereum testnet), how can i know the **exact time** (at **milli/micro/nano level**) which transaction executed (on miner side) first and which transaction executed later, by using java script. The etherscan just show all three trx time like high level i.e. `Timestamp: (Nov-08-2019 07:13:35 AM +UTC)`. I think there should be some time delay between each transaction !

Answer (score 1):

You should not think of Ethereum transactions in the same sense as regular messaging / transactions / background runs in the "traditional" world. Information like exact timestamps is really irrelevant in Ethereum.

A miner picks up transactions for his block and the miner decides in which order the transactions will be executed inside the block. All that matters is that 1) a transaction gets executed 2) in some cases, which transaction got executed after/before another transaction and 3) whether this block becomes a part of the canonical chain.

You basically have zero control over the decisions made by the miners (except incentivize with higher gas price). And even if you did, you have no way of knowing which miner manages to solve the mining puzzle in time. And even if you somehow knew even that you would have no way of knowing whether that block becomes an uncle block or stays in the main chain forever.

So, yes, the transactions do get executed at some exact timestamp but that exact timestamp is irrelevant. Furthermore the same transactions get executed a few thousand times across all the nodes so there would be thousands of different timestamps representing the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for your detail reply. I think , i could not elaborate my question well. Actually, i just want to know  the above mentioned time for the already mined transaction and become a part of confirmed block. For example, these are my two trx trx hash 1: 0x486b488070ecd4d5a75493100c1c8608cc5ea2d61b39550f4126eadab2c1808d   and trx hash 2 : 0x9f300f05a78c0f9ae0ffea8e4e6e8bd7b879988305495c12466b3621860c849d (already become a part of blockchain). Now is there any way, to get to know the time for both trx. Hope you got my point...

Comment: Those transactions are not in the mainnet but in Ropsten. They are both in the same block. You can see the block transactions here and their order but I don't think you can get any information about timestamps for individual transactions (mostly because of reasons I stated in my answer): https://ropsten.etherscan.io/txs?block=6733541

Comment: in case, i want to get requisite information from individual trx about timestamp, there should at least such facility. because it already saved on block with timestamp

Comment: Transactions don't have a timestamp, only the block has: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9858/solidity-is-there-a-way-to-get-the-timestamp-of-a-transaction-that-executed